# Proper REST endpoints when requesting reprocessing of failed asynchronous task

Tags: rest, http-verbs

Imagine a system for requesting files are upload from a particular URL.

```
http://example.com/{accountId}/files
```

A POST is made to that endpoint to initiate the file transfer. But given that the file can be large, and the process may take a while the server returns a 202 response.

After some time a GET is performed to

```
http://example.com/{accountId}/files/{fileId}
```

If the returned status of that file is still pending then we want to tell the server to attempt the transfer again, as we consider it timed out.

What I am stumped by is what the appropriate REST endpoint/HTTP verb would be to trigger the server to reprocess that file.

Comment: Seems like a slash in /files{fileId} is missing? SO won't let me fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding a "processor" resource that contains the status of the image processor:

```
http://example.com/{accountId}/files/{fileId}/processor
```

A GET on that could return JSON like this:

```
{
  "status": "Pending"
}
```

Clients could then restart the processor by issuing an empty POST to the processor resource. Further more the client could POST JSON with a "reason" value to be logged by the server (instead of just issuing an empty POST).

The base resource /{accountId}/files/{fileId} could include a link to the processor resource such that the client won't have to be hard coded with that information.

Comment: Close to where we ended up so I am accepting this. After some thought we added a resource {fileId}/status and we can do a PUT back to that resource to set the status to reprocess. That would trigger the action on the server.